# Making a textbox secure and uncrackable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a textbox that I have set to hidden and readonly like so

```
<div id="employeechosen" class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" name="chosen" id="chosen" class="form-control" required="" readonly>
</div>
```

What can I do to stop people from being able to enter anything they want beyond this? All a user would have to do is hit f12 and change input to text and delete readonly and proceed to do what I do not want them to able to do.

What is the best way to lock down a text box to not be compromised?

I chose the tags below because they are the languages I am using if there is anything that can be done in any of those languages.

Comment: There is no way to do this.

Comment: You can't. As long as validation logic exists on the client side, it can be manipulated.

Comment: hmmm so your saying use something like coldfusion and then write code to not allow the certain names i dont want to be able to be passed through?

Comment: @DavidBrierton you should tag server side language too...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must follow up client-side validation with additional server-side validation as well. It is the only way to ensure that you get valid data.

Comment: But what if its used for names and they change the name say from John to David but originally did not want david to be able to be chosen...

Comment: If this is your problem set the name in label not textbox

Comment: @DavidBrierton If they want to screw with your client-side code, just let them, because there is no way to prevent it. On the server-side, check that the data is correct, and if it's not, just throw an error at them.

Comment: @DavidBrierton You would have to set up your client and server-side validation logic to be checking for such things. Ultimately, it's your validation logic, so it can be checking for anything you want it to, but it must exist on the server to not be able to be tampered with.

Comment: @FarzinKanzi That makes no sense. ANY client-side code can be altered.

Comment: @David You will have to validate on the server side that an allowed value was submitted.

Comment: But label does not send to server and it is not important it change.

Comment: @FarzinKanzi A label must have a `for` attribute that matches a form-field and the `name` of the form field is what identifies the data to the receiving resource. Again, ANY HTML can be altered, not just form fields.

Comment: Yes I know it can be alternated. But  label and span are not fields to send data to server, And it doesn't matter client change these.

Comment: @FarzinKanzi Yes, those fields are not sent to the server, as such, they have no relationship to this issue at all. That's why I questioned you bringing them up.

Answer (score 1):

You have identified client side code as your only technologies to keep people from manipulating the data in the client.

**This is not possible.**

If you want to make it very difficult for them, you can create a JavaScript method that obfuscates the values in the hidden field via an encode/decode function, but if they are a good enough coder, they'll be able to reverse engineer your encoding and manipulate it.

The **only** way to ensure this is using server-side validation [as Scott Marcus said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42235987/4842817).

Comment: Obfuscation and hidden values are easily bypassed as well.

Comment: @Scott, I very explicitly recognized yours as the only way to ENSURE security. However, I also attempted to answer the question OP asked using the technology he specified, while noting that it was not a solution, merely an attempt at making a hacker's job more difficult.

Comment: My point was that, despite appearances, anyone who knows how to alter client-side code isn't going to be slowed down by obfuscation or hidden fields. They are simply not a deterrent.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to prevent bad data submission directly in the client is a good thing.

But you should always validate the submitted data on the server as well. Use validation logic, authentication and authorization to prevent attacks or unwanted behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

Do not depend on what you receive from front end. If someone is going through `F12`, they are not your website user (instead abuser). So better to keep track of the checkbox you should take help of-

On Client Side-

1. Cookies in JS
2. obfuscate the data

If Using Server Side Scripting-

1. Write values in database (After validation)
2. Keep values saved in Session (After validation)
3. Encrypt and pass values from one page to another

Comment: Both of your suggestions can be easily bypassed or tampered with. There is only one solution here and that is a second, server-side validation.

Comment: Server side? Validation? What is the need of validation here?

Comment: It is needed for exactly the question this post asks. As the data arrives at the server, it should be validated again to ensure that values were not manipulated on the client.

Comment: The question is not asking where to store data, it's asking how to ensure data doesn't bypass validation.

Comment: encryption and session are better method to do this.

Comment: Neither of those will have any impact on this issue. I don't think you understand the question. You keep posting answers that are unrelated.

Comment: @Scott he is not using any server side language. Please read the question.

Comment: I have and my answer tells him that it can't be done solely client-side. I go on to explain how to do it. You have posted 5 suggestions, none of which will do anything to help here.

Comment: Client side has everything open and he is seeking solution based on HTML/JS, so why everyone is forcing `server side`...

Answer (score -4):

Simple, add validation functionality. Both jQuery Validator and KnockoutJS are great tools with simple implementation for field validation. You can set the specific validation rules in order to prevent bad data submission.

Comment: Well i guess a little further into detail. The box is for a name. What happens when they just change a name... It will still validate as long as its not empty and fills the length requirements and such

Comment: A client-side library/framework is just as crackable as HTML.

Comment: IDK, I have never had an issue with bad data by simply using KO. If someone wants to mess with data bad enough - no server side or client side framework is going to prevent them if they know what they are doing. The idea is to mitigate risk.

Comment: OP, thank you for the clarification. So - will the boxes be pre-populated and you want to be able to prevent change - or are you trying to prevent them from changing the data after they enter it?

Comment: i have 6 dropdowns that are hidden. Based on which branch is chosen a list of names pops up. When they chose a name that will fill in the hidden textbox. I dont want them to easily hit f12 and put whatever name they want in it to be able to change anyones password lol

Comment: While there is no perfect solution here - one option might be to use JS to check the initial value of the field and store it in a var and then compare the content of the field with the saved value at time of submission. If they dont match, then use the saved value to repopulate the value that was maliciously changed. This will help prevent submissions if the values are not what is expected. Of course this could be cracked by someone determined enough - but it acts as the lock on the door, keeping out the opportunists.

Comment: I don't think you understand this issue. If a user modifies the client code, then that initial JS variable you suggested will have an altered value right from the start. There IS a way to ensure that invalid data doesn't get through and that is a server-side validity check. ALL client-side techniques are easily circumvented.

Comment: >If a user modifies the client code, then that initial JS variable you suggested will have an altered value right from the start. 


I mean that it stores the value assigned on pageload. Not after. The only time that var is accessed again would be when it compares prior to submit.